# how to extract string after some desired letters? using python 2.0 and numpy and pandas only

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I extract the string after the words "you attend at the" ?

```
"How satisfied, if at all, are you with the following stadium facilities at the Arabian Gulf League/Arabian Cup/Arabian Super Cup/President's Cup matches you attend at the Hazza bin Zayed Stadium (Al Ain)?"
```

Answer (score 1):

We could try just using `split` here, for a non regex option:

```
inp = "How satisfied, if at all, are you with the following stadium facilities at the Arabian Gulf League/Arabian Cup/Arabian Super Cup/President's Cup matches you attend at the Hazza bin Zayed Stadium (Al Ain)?"
output = inp.split('you attend at the')[1]
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
Hazza bin Zayed Stadium (Al Ain)?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('.*you attend at the ', '', "How satisfied, if at all, are you with the following stadium facilities at the Arabian Gulf League/Arabian Cup/Arabian Super Cup/President's Cup matches you attend at the Hazza bin Zayed Stadium (Al Ain)?")
'Hazza bin Zayed Stadium (Al Ain)?'
>>>
```

Or use:

```
>>> s = "How satisfied, if at all, are you with the following stadium facilities at the Arabian Gulf League/Arabian Cup/Arabian Super Cup/President's Cup matches you attend at the Hazza bin Zayed Stadium (Al Ain)?"
>>> s[s.find("you attend at the ") + 18:]
'Hazza bin Zayed Stadium (Al Ain)?'
>>>
```

Comment: cant use these packages, only need to use pandas and numpy

Comment: @VinayKurmi See the second example

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex:

`(?:you attend at the )(.*)`

You would be after the only group in the only match.

Comment: cant use these packages, only need to use pandas and numpy